# New Comment Insertion - Jquery ANimation

Tags: jquery

I am building an ajax powered comments insertion system and upon successful insertion of new comment I just append the added HTML to the comments section. I want to know how to produce a neat facebook type slidedown effect wwhen this new comment show up.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML node needs to be hidden initially. You can do this with

```
<div id="my_new_comment_id" style="display:none;">...content...</div>
```

You can then use jQuery's built in animation using something like

```
$('#my_new_comment_id').slideDown();
```

[jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)